# Multiple ACEs (Same group name) have different SIDs, Why?

Tags: c#, acl

so I came across this today and was wondering why this occurs.

```
DOM\Group1  S-1-5-21-19228943-1347772516-176895030-41916
DOM\Group1  S-1-5-21-693241485-1621911664-1232828436-6437
DOM\Group1  S-1-5-21-693241485-1621911664-1232828436-6438
DOM\Group1  S-1-5-21-693241485-1621911664-1232828436-6439
```

The first entry is the real SID and the others IDK why the SIDs show like that. I notice that with each additional entry the SID increments by 1.

This is not an isolated thing. Whenever there are multiple ACEs from the same group this occurs. I confirmed that the group is the same.

I am using this statement to get the group name from the SID:

```
new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(realSID).Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString();
```

Thanks

Comment: The 'why' behind this might be answered on [sf]?

Comment: Thanks. I posted it there.